how to make fields not 'required' in this node js model
In this node js model, all the field appear required. I don't want all of them to be 'required', i did the joi component of it but it is still not working
I removed the required() from the Joi validation but still i am getting the messages that the field is required
const { Schema, model } = require("mongoose");
const Joi = require("joi");

// Schema Definition

const AppointmentSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  age: Number,
  gender: String,
  email: String,
  phone: String,
  date: Date,
  time: String,
  disease: String,
  operation: String,
  comorbids: String,
  specialNotes: String,
  socialConnect: String,
  plan: String,
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});
const Appointment = model("Appointment", AppointmentSchema);

// Joi Validation

function validateAppointment(appointment) {
  const schema = Joi.object({
    name: Joi.string().min(3).required(),
    age: Joi.number().min(1).required(),
    gender: Joi.string().min(4).valid("male", "female", "other").required(),
    disease: Joi.string(),
    operation: Joi.string().min(3).required(),
    comorbids: Joi.string(),
    specialNotes: Joi.string(),
    socialConnect: Joi.string(),
    email: Joi.string().email(),
    phone: Joi.string().min(5),
    date: Joi.date().required(),
    time: Joi.string(),
  });

  return schema.validate(appointment);
}

exports.Appointment = Appointment;
exports.validate = validateAppointment;



how are you using the validate you are exporting?

router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
const { error } = validate(req.body);
if (error) {
return res.status(400).json({ message: error.details[0].message });
}
./rest of the code /
});

Ok so do you get status 400, and what error message?

message like ["disease"is not allowed to be empty]

Probably you are sending an empty string. In that case you should add Joi.string().optional().allow('')
